# Running max / limsup in Numpy: what optimization?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

In order to compute the [limsup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Definition_for_sequences) of a sequence, let's compute, for each `i`, the `max(A[i:])`:

```
import numpy as np
n = 10
A = np.random.random(n)
M = np.zeros(n)

for i in range(n):
    M[i] = np.max(A[i:])
```

Here is an example:

```
[ 0.85436167  0.92015564  0.44302976  0.56030154  0.16415721  0.39810583   0.65692947  0.5884984   0.57646131  0.0774121 ]
[ 0.92015564  0.92015564  0.65692947  0.65692947  0.65692947  0.65692947   0.65692947  0.5884984   0.57646131  0.0774121 ]
```

---

This is very very slow when `n` is 1 million.

**What optimization can be used to compute the array `M` efficiently?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace your `for` loop with the following code:

```
M = np.maximum.accumulate(A[::-1])[::-1]
```

This views the reverse of `A` and computes the cumulative maximum, then reverses this new array.

The performance of this code should be significantly better: the `for` loop method is of quadratic complexity, O(n<sup>2</sup>), and it incurs the overhead of the Python interpreter's bytecode execution on each iteration. On the other hand, the `np.maximum.accumulate` method is simply a single pass through the array in compiled code.

Comment: @Basj: `numpy.maximum` is a "ufunc", and all ufuncs have the `accumulate` method: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html